# How to use _id field with $lt operator

Tags: php, mongodb

It seems as if `less than` construct does not work, as I expect it. I try to  implement it like this:

```
...
while( $cursor->hasNext() ){
    $doc = $cursor->getNext();
    $last_id = $doc['_id']->{'$id'};
}
$condition = array('_id' => array('$lt' => $last_id));
$new_cursor = $collection->find($condition)->sort(array('_id' => -1))->limit(250);
```

I also tried '$gt', but in both situations I get empty result-sets. NB. $last_id is a valid id, which probably needs some conversion before I use it in condition block.

Comment: It's probably a string. Cast as an `ObjectId` to get the correct result.

Comment: Can you please advise me how should I cast it?

Comment: The manual can do that: [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php)

Answer (score -1):

For default, _id field is a ObjectId instance, which just a special 12-byte BSON type that guarantees uniqueness within the collection. So you are trying to compare random bytes as numbers. For autoincrement-like ids use counters http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: An ObjectId is "montonic" which means in laymans terms "ever increasing"

Comment: Yes, I'm incorrect. Comparing is available, if it ObjectId instance, but a driver can make a string type from it.

Comment: Nope an ObjectId is an ObjectId, which was the point of the question. Even represented as a string it is still lexical. So not useful..